# Tag [lp-spaces]

Tags: discussion, tagging

In this question,
[image]

the tag [lp-spaces](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/lp-spaces) has been created. I personally think it's not a bad idea , as it's a topic which frequently comes when we work on measure theory. The problem is that it's the first question with such a tag, so by definition the other ones which should be tagged like that are not.

So what do we have to do? I think among these question, those which don't need other edits, spelling, grammar, formatting, can be left like that. But what about the other one?

Comment: If we want this tag, it should be clarified what falls under that tag. (And the [tag-wiki](http://math.stackexchange.com/tags/lp-spaces/info) should be edited accordingly.) The way I see it, the questions on $\ell_p$ (including $\ell_\infty$) and $L_p$ (including $L_\infty$) could belong there.

Comment: @MartinSleziak I thought a similar description. I will edit the tag-wiki in order to make this more precise.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You asked: *So what do we have to do?*

My suggestion would be:

- At first we should add tag to the new questions, questions that were bumped for other reasons or only to few of older questions. In this way more people will notice the new tag and, if they think that the tag is not good for the site (as being too specific or for any other reason), then they can mention it at meta and the issue can be discussed. (The only reason I suggest slower pace at first is that if someone objects to the new tag and we decide to remove it, it would be easier to remove it from 50 questions than from, say, 250 questions.)
- If no reasonable objections are mentioned for some time, we can add tag to older question, but [in a reasonable pace](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5068/how-much-bumping-is-too-much/). (But I don't think that it is necessary trying to retag all older questions. This doesn't even seem feasible to me.) This is what we have done, when we introduced the tags [compactness](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/compactness) and [filters](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/filters), see [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/4399/would-tags-such-as-ultrafilters-or-stone-cech-compactification-be-too-specif). When you look into the questions bearing those tags, you will see that there are plenty of questions which are quite old - there were retagged after introducing those two tags.

When retagging, it is also good to check whether post can be improved in other ways (grammar, LaTeX, more descriptive title, ...) As the post is going to be bumped anyway, why not doing more useful things at once.

Comment: BTW it might also be useful to mention this meta thread in edit summary (at least while the tag is new), so that the OP and other people who see the edit know the reason for adding the tag. For example, I did this [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/posts/219972/revisions).